# How to a inject service from a feature module into another service in Angular

Tags: angular, angular14

I have a feature module named `MyModule` which provides a service named `ModalsService`, I want to inject this `ModalsService` into another service named `ApiService` which belongs to my main application and is marked as being provided in the root

```
@Injectable()
export class ModalsService { ... }
```

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    BetterModalsService
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
    constructor(
        private modalsService: ModalsService
    ) { }

    ...
}
```

Everything compiles without error but upon trying to call the `ModalsService` service from the `ApiService` I get an error that `this.modalsService` is undefined. I am also injecting the `ModalsService` service into some components from the main app which works as expected. This leads me to believe that there is some dependency injection trickery going on that I do not understand.

I've tried to use `providers: [ApiService]` in my `app.module.ts` rather than `providedIn: 'root'` but this makes no difference. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how you provice modal service and BetterModalsService?

Comment: share the exact error logs and if possible please create a stackblitz demo

Comment: @YogendraR Oh yeah that a good call, I'll go set one up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ApiService` is working fine because it has `{ providedIn: 'root' }` in its decorator `@Injectable`. An instance of a class (service) is created according to the Singleton pattern (one instance for the entire application).

While the `ModalsService` service is provided only in one of our modules - `MyModule`. In this case, we will have a service instance created if we import its module into our module where the ApiService is located, and it will be used.

So, you have two solutions:

1. Import the module of the `ModalsService` (`MyModule`) into the module of the `ApiService` and it should work.
2. Set the `{ providedIn: 'root' }` in the decorator of `ModalsService`. But I don't recommend this way, it's not the best practice. We use it only in special situations.

I think this should help you.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, I do import MyModule though I indeed forgot to show that in my question. Making a minimal reproducible example in stackblitz has proven impossible because everything seems to work fine there, so I deleted the `.angular` folder and rebuilt the whole project and now it is no longer undefined. Just one of those magic corrupted built cache problems I guess...

Comment: I'll still accept your answer though, it might help someone who forgets to import their feature module.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes this situation can happen and re-creating the project can also help :)